# Which generic word to use in a table of responsibilities to describe "action, work"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I have a table of responsibilities under a short project. I cannot quote the real table in Russian, so I composed a similar one:

> [image]

Would "execution" fit the purpose? Whereas in the line "Plan of work" we have more specific descriptions of what each person does, in other lines I just need a word that describes generic action (perform tests, log deviations, grant an approval etc.) The Russian word in my original document is **[выполнение](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E2%FB%EF%EE%EB%ED%E5%ED%E8%E5)**.

Comment: Why not reorder the table with columns of "Owner" "Reviewer" and "Approver"  then put the appropriate name in each cell.

Comment: Is 'completion' suitable, rather than 'execution' ? 'Execution' is ambiguous, meaning either the ongoing execution of a task or its final outcome; whereas 'completion' is definitely the finished article.

Comment: @Jim - I'm a mere translator, I can't rename columns.. Can I just use **action owner** instead of **execution**?